# BlenderGIS map define country borders instead of rectangle

Tags: height-map

I just found Blender and BlenderGIS and got determined to output a country relief map. As of now following many tutorials I can generate the map with elevation details.
In every tutorial, they are mentioning to

1. Set a basemap
2. press <kbd>G</kbd> and type location
3. Press <kbd>E</kbd>

Which generates a rectangle area. I cannot find any details about defining the borders so only a city map is generated instead of rectangle area map. Even though SRTM data generates a 3D projection it still is a rectangle instead of a defined area like California or Texas.

Please guide me how to go forward on this issue.

Comment: This Q&A site can only answer questions about using Blender and its built-in addons. BlenderGIS is a third-party addon so you'll have to look elsewhere to ask questions about it. The Wiki page seems to be [here](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki) so you might find answers there.